NUT UPS server not executing shell script when onbattery trigger
Can someone please help me with this, not sure what I am doing wrong here.
I have a Raspberry Pi running NUT Server which is connected to my UPS via USB.
I am trying to get the NUT server to execute my scripts when it goes on battery. My scripts are basically shell scripts which are calling a PowerShell script which uses Power CLI to shut down my VMware systems.
These work fine when I manually call them via PowerShell, via the shell script and I can call the triggers manually by doing /usr/bin/upssched-cmd shutdownservers and it works fine. But for some reason it does not work when I pull the power from the UPS. The email scripts work fine within the shell scripts. Not sure what is going on.
The below shell script is a test script I am using, just to ensure this whole things works. This script calls out to vcenter and performs a shut-down of a single VM.
#!/bin/sh

#Will execute powershell first
pwsh /Scripts/TestScripts/Test_VmwareTest1.ps1 
#wait
#echo 'VMWARE has now successfully shutdown, sleeping for 60seconds to shutdown Truenas!!'
#sleep 120
#./Test_TruenasShutdown.sh
sleep 10
/Scripts/EmailAlertMessages/EmailAlert-ShutdownComplete.sh

exit

When I pull the mains on the UPS the email is triggered to say it is on battery, then another email to say it is going to perform the shutdown script. But it never seems to execute the shutdown script.
Below is my NUT configs.
The UPSSCHED-CMD is configured as follows:
#!/bin/sh
UPS_USERNAME="admin"
UPS_PASSWORD="pwd"
UPS_LINK="APCUPS01@localhost"
case $1 in
    onbatt)
        # Enable beeper
        #upscmd -u ${UPS_USERNAME} -p ${UPS_PASSWORD} ${UPS_LINK} beeper.enable
        # Send notification to journalctl and email alert
        logger -t upssched-cmd "The UPS is on battery!"
        /Scripts/EmailAlertMessages/EmailAlert-OnBattery.sh
        ;;
    online)
        # Put notification in the journalctl and send notification email
        logger -t upssched-cmd "The UPS is back online!"
        /Scripts/EmailAlertMessages/EmailAlert-BackOnline.sh
        ;;
    shutdownservers)
        # Begin to shudown all systems
        logger -t upssched-cmd "The shutdown script has now been called!"
        /Scripts/EmailAlertMessages/EmailAlert-Shutdown.sh
        /Scripts/TestScripts/Test_Shutdown.sh
        ;;
    mute_beeper)
        # Mute the beeper after 30s
        upscmd -u ${UPS_USERNAME} -p ${UPS_PASSWORD} ${UPS_LINK} beeper.mute
        ;;
esac

UPSSCHED.CONF
CMDSCRIPT /usr/bin/upssched-cmd
PIPEFN /etc/nut/upssched.pipe
LOCKFN /etc/nut/upssched.lock


# ============================================================================


# Send out Alerts 
AT ONBATT * EXECUTE onbatt
AT ONLINE * EXECUTE online


# Begin Shutdown of servers - execute Shutdown.sh
AT ONBATT * START-TIMER shutdownservers 5


# Cancel timer of shutdownservers if battery comes back online
AT ONLINE * CANCEL-TIMER shutdownservers online


# If battery is low execute the shutdownservers commands immediately
AT LOWBATT * EXECUTE shutdownservers


# (Optional) Silence the beeper after 2 minutes
AT ONBATT * START-TIMER mute_beeper 30
AT ONLINE * CANCEL-TIMER mute_beeper

UPSMON.CONF
RUN_AS_USER root

MONITOR APCUPS01@localhost 1 admin pwd master

MINSUPPLIES 1
NOTIFYCMD /usr/sbin/upssched
POLLFREQ 2
POLLFREQALERT 1
HOSTSYNC 15
DEADTIME 15

NOTIFYMSG ONLINE    "UPS %s on line power"
NOTIFYMSG ONBATT    "UPS %s on battery"
NOTIFYMSG LOWBATT   "UPS %s battery is low"
NOTIFYMSG FSD       "UPS %s: forced shutdown in progress"
NOTIFYMSG COMMOK    "Communications with UPS %s established"
NOTIFYMSG COMMBAD   "Communications with UPS %s lost"
NOTIFYMSG SHUTDOWN  "Auto logout and shutdown proceeding"
NOTIFYMSG REPLBATT  "UPS %s battery needs to be replaced"
NOTIFYMSG NOCOMM    "UPS %s is unavailable"
NOTIFYMSG NOPARENT  "upsmon parent process died - shutdown impossible"


NOTIFYFLAG ONLINE   SYSLOG+WALL+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG ONBATT   SYSLOG+WALL+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG LOWBATT  SYSLOG+WALL+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG FSD      SYSLOG+WALL
NOTIFYFLAG COMMOK   SYSLOG+WALL
NOTIFYFLAG COMMBAD  SYSLOG+WALL
NOTIFYFLAG SHUTDOWN SYSLOG+WALL+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG REPLBATT SYSLOG+WALL+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG NOCOMM   SYSLOG+WALL
NOTIFYFLAG NOPARENT SYSLOG+WALL


RBWARNTIME 43200


NOCOMMWARNTIME 600


FINALDELAY 5

The permissions on the scripts are the same what is set on the top level folders as below.
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec  2 19:36 EmailAlertMessages
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  146 Dec  2 20:42 RestartNUTServices.sh
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec  2 19:36 Shutdown
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec  2 19:36 TestScripts

I installed powershell with this.
sudo tar zxf /tmp/powershell.tar.gz -C /opt/microsoft/powershell/7
sudo chmod +x /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh
sudo ln -s /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh

The permissions of the PowerShell command is
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 72568 Oct 16 17:50 /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh

If run upssched-cmd shutdownservers it works - see screenshot
manual run
Does anyone have any idea what i am doing wrong here.

Is the directory with the pwsh binary in the PATH environment variable for the upssched service (and for the scripts it runs)?

Hi, most likely not. I installed powershell then used this command to make it available to all users. I thought it ran as ROOT because i got it set as RUN_AS_USER root in my UPSMON.config.
sudo ln -s /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh.  The commands run fine if i use bash or pwsh or even try excute it on the command line with upssched-cmd. As mentioned above

Environment (including PATH) is not per-user, it is per-process. What does your script when run by upsmon/upssched report from echo $PATH or printenv PATH (or some logger equivalent)? And if you used that ln -s command to symlink pwsh – where did you symlink it to? Did you link it to /usr/bin or somewhere else? The command you mention doesn't specify the link path...

I ran this to make it available to everyone:
sudo ln -s /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh
By doing so i can just type pwsh and it enters powershell mode now.
@grawity is this what you meant?
pi@PI-UPS:~ $ upssched-cmd $PATH pi@PI-UPS:~ $ upssched $PATH Error: UPSNAME and NOTIFYTYPE must be set. This program should only be run from upsmon. pi@PI-UPS:~ $ upsmon $PATH
The script runs if i type this in the terminal manually
upssched-cmd onbatt
but nothing when i pull plug

@grawity I just updated the post with a screenshot so you can see the scripts run manually fine.
